# Jasmine test cases for the angularjs with step-by-step procedure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here is the code. I need jasmine test cases for the following JS: I am new to the jasmine, but i tried with sample but wont work. please help me

app.js file

```
var employeeApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

employeeApp.controller("employeeController", function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

            $http.get('data/employees.json').success(function(data) {

                $rootScope.employees = data;
            }); 

            var empId = 12342;
            $rootScope.saveEmployeeRecord = function(emp) {
                if($rootScope.employees.EmployeeId == null) {
                    $rootScope.employees.EmployeeId = empId++;
                    $rootScope.employees.push(emp);
                }
                else {
                    for(i in $rootScope.employees) {
                        if($rootScope.employees[i].EmployeeId == emp.EmployeeId) { 
                            $rootScope.employees[i]= emp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //$rootScope.employees = {};
            }

            $rootScope.resetEmployeeRecord = function() {
                angular.copy({}, $rootScope.employees);
            }

            $rootScope.editEmployee = function(emp, indx) {

                    //$rootScope.emp = $rootScope.employees;
                    if($rootScope.employees[indx].EmployeeId == emp.EmployeeId) { 
                        $rootScope.employees = angular.copy($rootScope.employees[indx]);
                    }


            }

            $rootScope.DeleteEmployee = function(idx) {

                var result = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
                if (result) {
                    $rootScope.employees.splice(idx,1);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                     return false;
                }

                //for(i in $rootScope.employees) {
                    //if($rootScope.employees[i].EmployeeId == idx) { 

                        //$rootScope.employees = {};
                    //}
                //}
            }

});
```

Here is the json file

```
[
            {
                "EmployeeId": "61234",
                "LastName": "Anderson",
                "FirstName": "James",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Email": "james_anderson@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Boeing"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "512458",
                "LastName": "Cambell",
                "FirstName": "Mike",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Email": "mike.cambell@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Boeing"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "712785",
                "LastName": "Swachengar",
                "FirstName": "Andrew",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Email": "andrew.swachengar@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Cisco"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "712734",
                "LastName": "Anderson",
                "FirstName": "James",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Email": "james.anderson@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Apple"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "61245",
                "LastName": "Green",
                "FirstName": "Rachael",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Email": "rachael_green@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Boeing"
            },
            {
                "EmployeeId": "61347",
                "LastName": "Brown",
                "FirstName": "Jackualine",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Email": "jackualine_brown@infosys.com",
                "Account": "Boeing"
            }
]
```

include in spec runner.html

```
<script src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/Angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/app.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/app_test.js"></script>
```

test case
app_test.js

'use strict';
describe('myApp', function() {

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

describe("employeeController", function() {

```
   var scope, httpBackend;

    var mockEmployees = [{
        "EmployeeId": "61234",
            "LastName": "Anderson",
            "FirstName": "James",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Email": "james_anderson@infosys.com",
            "Account": "Boeing"
    }, {
        "EmployeeId": "512458",
            "LastName": "Cambell",
            "FirstName": "Mike",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Email": "mike.cambell@infosys.com",
            "Account": "Boeing"
    }, {
        "EmployeeId": "712785",
            "LastName": "Swachengar",
            "FirstName": "Andrew",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Email": "andrew.swachengar@infosys.com",
            "Account": "Cisco"
    }, {
        "EmployeeId": "712734",
            "LastName": "Anderson",
            "FirstName": "James",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Email": "james.anderson@infosys.com",
            "Account": "Apple"
    }];

    var mockedEditEmployeeService, emptyPromise;
   beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
       httpBackend = $httpBackend;



       scope = $rootScope;
       mockedEditEmployeeService = {
               editEmployee: emptyPromise
           };

       $controller('employeeController', {$scope: scope});
   }));

   it('should fetch list of users', function(){

       httpBackend.whenGET("../data/employees.json").respond(mockEmployees);

       httpBackend.expectGET("../data/employees.json");
       console.log(scope.employees);
       //httpBackend.flush();
       var spyEvent = spyOn(mockedEditEmployeeService, 'editEmployee').and.callThrough();;
       expect(mockedEditEmployeeService.editEmployee).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

});

});

I have tried but it shows spy on edit employee not defined and some other errors shown. I tried more posiblity. But not able to do. I am new to this please help me.

please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: @show-me-the-code Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a couple of quick points about your controller. Don't use rootScope like you are doing. It's bad practice. Your data access should be in a service, which the controller should then consume. Without seeing the Jasmine suites, we have no way to know what you have or have not tried, and nobody here is going to write your tests for you.

Comment: @MBielski I have updated with the code changes of test cases i have tried but it show some error. please help me